# Full code completion with inline resources

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, code-completion

When I have inline stylesheet tag `<style>...</style>` in a file, code completion shows only the specific styles that are defined in the file.

If I delete this style section the code completion will work fine and shows all the external resources(i.e bootstrap styles,...).

Is it possible to have all external and inline resources at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-2223](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2223) ans linked tickets